# global functions accessing system features android

Tags: android

hi i have created a global actions class and created functions inside this class which i'm trying to access inside another activity the problem i'm having is that in eclipse I'm getting coding errors around the functions that access system feature such as getSystemService() and getApplicationContext() does anyone know why or how to let a global class accept system features?

heres what i have so far heres my GloblActions.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.util.Log;

public class GlobalActions{
        Context mContext;

        // constructor
        public GlobalActions(Context context){
            this.mContext = context;
        }


        public final static boolean isOnline (Context someContext){ {

            Log.v("globals", "isonline");

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) someContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
        }

}



        public final static void checkInternet(Context someContext){

                    isOnline(someContext);
                    if(isOnline(someContext) == false){
                       Log.v("globals", "isOnline = false");
                       Intent register = new Intent(someContext.getApplicationContext(), LoginForm.class);
                       someContext.startActivity(register);
                    }
                }



        }
```

heres where i'm using the function in an activity. my goal is is to check internet connection on every activity by just calling the global function and if no connection is found go to an activity that says no internet connection.

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Handler;
import com.myApp.myApp.GlobalActions;

public class IntroLoader extends Activity {

    public Handler handler;
    public TextView loadText = null;
    public Animation AniFadein = null;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lo_introloader);
        findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.loadTextView).setVisibility(View.GONE);
         GlobalActions.isOnline(null);
         GlobalActions.checkInternet(null);

        handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable fadeIn = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() 
            {
               animations();
               findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               findViewById(R.id.loadTextView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                         }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(fadeIn, 3000);

        final Runnable aSyncTask= new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() 
            {

               PostTask posttask;
               posttask = new PostTask();
               posttask.execute();

            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(aSyncTask, 4000);

    }

    public void animations(){

        loadText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.loadTextView);
        AniFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);  
        loadText.startAnimation(AniFadein); 

    }


  public class PostTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Boolean> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            boolean result = false;
            publishProgress("progress");
            return result;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 1; i < progress.length; i++) {
                    str.append(progress[i] + " ");

                }
        }

            @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            checkLoginData();
          }
    }

  public void checkLoginData(){

      Intent register = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginForm.class);
      startActivity(register);


  }         



}
```

Comment: You may want to look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: @MrZander I wouln't recommend extending Application and neither do the docs: *"There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do

```
 ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Contexts can use the method `getSystemService()` but your class isn't a Context, you need to use your `mContext` variable.

This means that you can also replace `getApplicationContext()` with `mContext`. And if you *really* need `getApplicationContext()` (unlikely - normal Contexts should work fine), use

```
mContext.getApplicationContext()
```

Also, you declare your `isOnline()` method as static, but then you need to use a Context for checking and making the toast. Either don't make it static *or* change it so it accepts in a Context, eg

```
public final static boolean isOnline (Context someContext){
```

And replace calls there that need a Context with `someContext`. Static methods don't need an instance of the class, and so, you can't use `mContext`. Once you fix the `getApplicationContext()` issue you have now, the compiler should throw an error about accessing a non static field in a static way. Same with your `checkInternet()`. I suggest you revaluate your logic, there are multiple problems with your class - I suggest making everything a static method that accepts in a Context which will be given by the calling Activity.

Lastly be careful about showing Toasts and other UI Elements in a global non-ui class. Toasts should be fine since they run on top of windows, but a Dialog will need a window, and if `mContext` is not an instance of `Activity`, that will fail (Activities have a window, other Contexts (like `getApplicationContext()`), do not.

Comment: hi this is great thank you nice to have an answer not only given but explained. one thing i'm having an issue with is is asking me to change modifier of mContext to static which is causing it to break still do you know why this is?

Comment: @LukeBatley you can't access non-static fields in a static method. I really suggest you make this whole class contain only static methods and have each Activity pass itself off as a Context for each method call. Having this class be instantiated (via `new`) is a waste - not to mention is causes more problems.

Comment: thanks for your help i have edited my code to what i think you were suggesting is what i have done correct?

Comment: @LukeBatley seems correct to me. Note that now you don't need the constructor nor do you need `Context mContext;`.

Comment: I'm getting a null pointer exception error at ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) someContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

Comment: You're passing off null in the Activity: `GlobalActions.isOnline(null); GlobalActions.checkInternet(null);` replace null in this case with `this`.

Comment: thank you so much its been a pleasure to talk to someone so willing to help thanks very much

Comment: hi sorry to bother you could take a look at my latest question as you were so helpful last time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873137/passing-functions-into-a-global-asynctask-android