# Passing functions into a global AsyncTask Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to create a global actions file in which i can call certain functions globally anywhere within the app. so far i have got it working with functions etc but now what i'm wanting to do is put a standard AsyncTask into my global actions and pass it functions/voids from my Activity so i'd want to pass it a function to run in background and a function to run once finished. does anyone know how do this? and also advise me on running multiple functions on a background thread do i create one AsyncTask and feed in multiple functions or do i create multiple AsyncTasks?

heres an example of what i have managed to do globally so far and how i'm currently implementing my Asynctask. Just to reiterate i'm trying to move the asynctask into a global actions and make it as reusuable as possible

in my Global Actions im creating a function that formulates a URL and sends post variables to that url which then feedsback a JSON response. then in my Activity i have created a function to both call that request and then Log the response

My Global Actions

```
  public final static JSONObject startAPICallRequest(Context activityContext, String requestReference, String callLocation, Map<String, String> postVarsMap, Map<String, String> getVarsMap){

            long unixTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;

            StringBuilder extraGetVarsString = new StringBuilder();
            if(getVarsMap != null){
                Map<String, String> map = (Map)getVarsMap;
                for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    extraGetVarsString.append("&" + entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
                    extraGetVarsString.toString();
                }
            }

            String appVersion = null;

            try {
                appVersion = activityContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(activityContext.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;

            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                appVersion = activityContext.getResources().getString(R.string.appVersion);
            }
            String getVarsString = "?timestamp=" + unixTimeStamp + "&app_version=" + appVersion + extraGetVarsString;
            String apiLocation = activityContext.getResources().getString(R.string.apiLocation);
            String fullAPIURL = apiLocation + callLocation + getVarsString;

            Log.v("globals", "fullAPIURL=" + fullAPIURL);   

            String api_key = activityContext.getResources().getString(R.string.apiKey);
            String api_user = activityContext.getResources().getString(R.string.apiUser);
            String request_token = returnSHAFromString(api_key, fullAPIURL);
            String device_id = returnStringFromPreference(activityContext,"device_id");
            String user_token = returnStringFromPreference(activityContext,"user_token");

            List<NameValuePair> postVarsList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postVarsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request_token", request_token));
            postVarsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_user", api_user));
            postVarsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_id", device_id));
            postVarsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_token", user_token));

            if(postVarsMap != null){
                Map<String, String> map = (Map)postVarsMap;
                for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    postVarsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
                }
            }


            JSONObject responseJSON = null;

            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(fullAPIURL);
                post.setEntity (new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postVarsList));

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                String jsonResponse = reader.readLine();

                Log.v("globals", "postList =" + postVarsList );

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

            return responseJSON;

        }
```

MY Activity

```
public void apiCall(){
        responseJSON = GlobalActions.startAPICallRequest(this, "login", "my-network/", null, null);
    }


  public class PostTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Boolean> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

            apiCall();
            boolean result = false;
            publishProgress("progress");

            return result;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 1; i < progress.length; i++) {
                    str.append(progress[i] + " ");

                }
        }

            @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            checkLoginData();
          }
    }

  public void checkLoginData(){

      Log.v("IntroLoader", "responseJSON = " + responseJSON);
      Intent register = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginForm.class);
      startActivity(register);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `AsyncTask` for calling REST API methods is not really correct approach. Your code has 2 problems:

- There is no guarantee that your API call will be finished when Activity is closed because process can be killed
- You have memory leak because `PostTask` can hold Activity reference even while Activity can be already destroyed

Consider using [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) for making background requests and e. g. [ResultReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html) for handling results in your `Activity`.

Comment: interesting ive never used intentservice before could you show me how to implement it in my code please?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a Handler and a Looper. You will be able to post() and postDelayed(). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

See also:
[Is AsyncTask really conceptually flawed or am I just missing something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357477/is-asynctask-really-conceptually-flawed-or-am-i-just-missing-something)

Comment: hi thans for this was an interesting post. im not entirely sure what you mean abut handlers and loopers and how could i implement that in to my code

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Java expert but I don't think you pass functions around in Java. To simplify the matter, what you want to do is call a function in your Activity class when AsyncTask is complete?